# Are atom coordinates in molfile necessary to produce a valid InChI identifier

Tags: cheminformatics, structural-formula, identification, chemical-formula

I took this molfile of benzoic acid:

```
  ACD/Labs0708041726  

  9  9  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1 V2000
   13.2076   -5.2994    0.0000 C   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
   14.3539   -4.6250    0.0000 C   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
   13.2076   -6.6480    0.0000 C   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
   15.5003   -5.2994    0.0000 C   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
   14.3539   -3.2763    0.0000 C   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
   14.3539   -7.3224    0.0000 C   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
   15.5003   -6.6480    0.0000 C   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
   13.2076   -2.6020    0.0000 O   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
   15.5003   -2.6020    0.0000 O   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
  1  2  2  0  0  0  0
  1  3  1  0  0  0  0
  2  4  1  0  0  0  0
  2  5  1  0  0  0  0
  3  6  2  0  0  0  0
  4  7  2  0  0  0  0
  5  8  1  0  0  0  0
  5  9  2  0  0  0  0
  6  7  1  0  0  0  0
M  END
```

and used `inchi-1` program to produce this InChI identifier:

```
InChI=1S/C7H6O2/c8-7(9)6-4-2-1-3-5-6/h1-5H,(H,8,9)
```

When I edit molfile and make all atom coordinates identical, e.g. `13.2076   -5.2994    0.0000`, `inchi-1` produces the same InChI identifier.

Is this a fluke or a normal behavior? I see that atom coordinates are placed into `AuxInfo=...` string. Are there cases when correct atom coordinates are required in order to produce a valid `InChI=1S...` string?

Comment: Apparently, it is derived from the connectivity table and not from the coordinates.

Comment: It seems so. I found a definitive answer, which I will post.

Comment: For the interested (accidentally describing benzoic acid), the [anatomy of a MOL file](https://chem.libretexts.org/Courses/University_of_Arkansas_Little_Rock/ChemInformatics_(2017)%3A_Chem_4399_5399/2.2%3A_Chemical_Representations_on_Computer%3A_Part_II/2.2.2%3A_Anatomy_of_a_MOL_file), although there is a relevant entry on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chemical_table_file), too.

Answer (score 4):

Quoting from "InChI, the IUPAC International Chemical Identifier" article [Heller et al. Journal of Cheminformatics (2015) 7:23]:

> Each atom is described by a number of properties: its
> chemical element name; x,y,z- coordinates (all or any of
> them may be zero);

When I edit all coordinates to zero, `inchi-1` produces a valid InChI identifier:

```
InChI=1S/C7H6O2/c8-7(9)6-4-2-1-3-5-6/h1-5H,(H,8,9)
```

and auxiliary info, which reflect no valid atom coordinates available:

```
AuxInfo=1/1/N:6,3,7,1,4,2,5,8,9/E:(2,3)(4,5)(8,9)/rA:9nCCCCCCCOO/rB:d1;s1;s2;s2;d3;d4s6;s5;d5;/rC:;;;;;;;;;
```

I did a similar test earlier, but I didn't retain the strict 10 character column width for each coordinate, which produced an error:

```
Error 34 (no InChI; Cannot interpret atom block line:     0.0000  0.0000    0.0000
```

Comment: For a simple compound like benzoic acid, OpenBabel certainly accepts the SMILES string containing no coordinate information at all as sufficient input to reply to `obabel -:'O=C(O)c1ccccc1' -oinchi`  by `InChI=1S/C7H6O2/c8-7(9)6-4-2-1-3-5-6/h1-5H,(H,8,9)`, too.  Of course SMILES simplify and thus possess limitations in representing a structure uniquely and unambiguously, thus the restraining «for a simple compound» at the beginning.